# MySQL calculate percentage of two other calculated sums including a group by month

Tags: mysql, sql

Say i have 3 tables with a model like this

[image]

The result i want to have now looks like this

[image]

I want to calculate turnovers and profits made by all employees per month and compare it to the last years SAME month and calculate the difference in percentage of the profits. It should include the last 12 months with the INTERVAL function.

```
select
  bookings.b_emp_id as "Employee",
  MONTH(bookings.b_date) as Month,
  @turnover1 := sum(bookings.b_turnover) as '2017-turnover',
  @turnover2 := (select sum(lx.b_turnover) 
                 from bookings as lx 
                 where lx.b_date = date_add(bookings.b_date, INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
                 GROUP BY 
                   MONTH(bookings.b_date),
                   YEAR(bookings.b_date), 
                   bookings.b_emp_id
                ) as '2016-turnover',
  sum(b_profit) as '2017-profit',
  @profit1 := (select sum(lx.umsatz_fees) 
               from bookings as lx 
               where lx.b_date = date_add(bookings.b_date,INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
               GROUP BY 
                 MONTH(bookings.b_date),
                 YEAR(bookings.b_date),
                 bookings.b_emp_id
              ) as '2016-profit'
from bookings 
where bookings.b_date > '2017-01-01'
  and bookings.b_emp_id = ´SA´ 
GROUP BY MONTH(bookings.b_date)
order by bookings.b_date desc
```

Comment: Can you please post your query as well, and describe the issues you having within it..

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i edited the post with my query but the result is only for 1 employee and the calculation of the difference needs to be added too

Comment: Why a view specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by that im not using any views here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation. It is not clear if you want to look at the last 12 / 24 months, or at the months of 2017 and the same months in 2016. Neither do I understand how you want to calculate a percentage. I divide this year's profits by last year's in below query. Adjust this so it meets your needs.

```
select
  b_emp_id,
  month,
  turnover_this_year,
  profit_this_year,
  turnover_last_year,
  profit_last_year,
  profit_this_year / profit_last_year * 100 as diff
from
(
  select
    b_emp_id,
    month(b_date) as month,
    sum(case when year(b_date) = year(curdate()) then b_turnover end) as turnover_this_year,
    sum(case when year(b_date) = year(curdate()) then b_profit end) as profit_this_year,
    sum(case when year(b_date) < year(curdate()) then b_turnover end) as turnover_last_year,
    sum(case when year(b_date) < year(curdate()) then b_profit end) as profit_last_year
  from bookings
  where year(b_date) in (year(curdate()), year(curdate()) - 1)
    and month(b_date) <= month(curdate())
  group by b_emp_id, month(b_date)
) figures
order by b_emp_id, month;
```

Comment: What if i want to look at the last 12/24 Months how would that look

Comment: `where bdate > curdate() - interval 24 month` and `sum(case when bdate > curdate() - interval 12 month then ...`. But then I'd change the order by to `order by month <= month(curdate()), b_emp_id, month` and/or display the years (e.g. month 12, years 2015/2016).

Comment: there are employees that started working this year, is it possible to sort them out so there are no null entries ?

Comment: So there is a date in the employee table? I'd add something like `and b_emp_id in (select emp_id from employee where startdate < curdate() - interval 12 month)` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: there is no date in the employee table was just asking if it is possible to sort entries out so it only shows the employees that worked this year and sort out the ones that are not working anymore but worked the last year

Comment: You only want employees that have bookings records in both years? Then add `having sum(bdate > curdate() - interval 12 month) > 0 and sum(bdate <= curdate() - interval 12 month) > 0`.

Comment: this worked but there is still two null entries in this years turnover and profit i couldnt figure out why maybe because it is the current month (11)